# Динамически подключаемая библиотека

Tags: linux, c

Динамически подключаю библиотеку при помощи функции void *dlopen(const char *filename, int flag);
Как мне в самом коде библиотеки узнать, какое количество программ подключило и использует данную библиотеку?

Answer (score 1):

Если посмотреть на документацию на функцию [dlopen](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen), то там видно, что при загрузке библиотеки, линковщик вызывает функцию `_init()` (но она сейчас считается устаревшей или функцию с атрибутом `__attribute__((constructor))`. А при выгрузке - `_fini`/`__attribute__((destructor))`. Там делайте счетчик и соответственно увеличивать/уменьшать счетчик.

Способ номер два. В каталоге `/proc/..../map_files` пробежаться по всем файлам и посмотреть, нет ли там Вашей. И счетчик увеличивать. Где то так

```
ls /proc/*/map_files/ -al | grep libc | wc -l
```

правда можно заметить, что некоторые библиотеки загружены по несколько раз. Как это интерпретировать - зависит от Вас.